# Is the Intel stack pointer pointing to the latest item or next item?

Tags: assembly, intel

Does %esp point to the current item on the stack or the free address that will be used by the next PUSH instruction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The description for `PUSH` in Intel's manual answers that pretty well:

```
ESP  ← ESP – 4;
Memory[SS:ESP]  ← SRC;
```

As you can see, the stack pointer is pre-decremented, so after the `PUSH` the stack pointer will be pointing to the value you just pushed.

Comment: How does it know the length of the current item on the stack, whether it's 32-bits or 64 bits, so that it will know how much to decrement on the next PUSH instruction?

Comment: It doesn't need to know. The stack moves backwards.

Comment: I only showed the dword case. The amount by which the stack pointer is decremented obviously depends on the operand size. Refer to the manual if you want to read the full description. However, the CPU doesn't know _"the length of the current item on the stack"_. That's something you as the programmer is supposed to keep track of.

Comment: it's rather<br>
ESP  ← ESP –  sizeof(src);<br>
Memory[SS:ESP]  ← SRC;<br>
and it must be this way, for you cannot predict what the next value's size will be, so you cannot point to "the next free address"

Comment: @Michael, I am trying to understand your answer. You showed the PUSH first decrementing ESP by 4. Am I right to say prior to this, ESP is pointing to the last pushed item?  If so, how does it know whether the last pushed item is 4 bytes or something else?

Comment: you have to know what you're popping ;)

Comment: _"how does it know whether the last pushed item is 4 bytes or something else?"_ The CPU doesn't need to know anything about the stack contents when you do a `PUSH`. All it needs to know is the size of the value you're pushing _now_. `PUSH` decrements `esp` to make room for the new value, not because of whatever you've pushed on the stack earlier.

Comment: Thanks. I get it now. It decrements the amount to store the **current** item being pushed. It is subtracting, so the item will occupy the ESP address to the previous ESP address-1. I was confused with the effects of an incrementing pointer.

Comment: To add to that, contrary to Intel's insn ref, in 64bit mode only 16bit and 64bit pushes are available.  A REX prefix with the `W` bit = 0 is an illegal instruction, so you can't do a 32bit push in 64bit mode.  (At least not with the push instruction.  Obviously you can `sub $4, %esp` / `mov %r32, (esp)`)

Comment: Can someone post the document reference you all are referring to. I am a System/360 assembler dinosaur. Thanks.

Comment: Links in the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).  I'm too lazy to pull the specific link out of the wiki, but I did make it bold and easy to find when I tidied it up.

Comment: @PeterCordes, thanks. I wanted to find out what 'test $0x1,$%dl` mean and went to https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/. I entered `test` and about 50 entries were returned but none of them is a TEST mnemonic. Am I missing something basic?

Comment: Yes.  The Intrinsics guide only lists C/C++ functions.  Most of them map directly to a single instruction, but not every instruction has an intrinsic.  The only effect of `test` is to set flags, and the C language doesn't have any notion of flags (just boolean results, like you'd get from `int a = (x>y)`).  You don't need any special C wrapper to get a compiler to make good use of the `test` instruction, so there's no intrinsic for it.  There are intrinsics for some non-vector instructions, like `popcnt` / `bsf` / `tzcnt`, and other BMI1 / BMI2 insns.